# Computer goes into power save mode when lid is closed?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, power-management

I've set my computer not do anything when the lid is closed and it usually goes smoothly, but I recently realized that my downloads go a lot slower when the lid id closed. My fiance and I think it might be because it goes into power save mode when the lid is closed. Is there a way to turn this off or is it something else slowing down my downloads? I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: Actually your wireless antennae are in the lid. You're probably attenuating the signal by closing the lid. Try plugging in with an Ethernet cable and testing. Or sit the laptop next to your wireless router.

Comment: Oh sorry, by downloads I didn't mean like downloads downloads. I meant like I'm converting videos and the conversion process slows down (no internet connection required).

Answer (score 2):

Some laptop designs can’t dissipate as much heat with the lid closed. Closing the lid can block vents and block convection currents over the trackpad and palm rests and other surfaces around the keyboard. So those laptops often run their processors slower with the lid closed so the laptop won’t overheat. It’s not something you want to turn off, unless you want thermal damage.